# How can i hide General tab on media plugin, tinymce

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm trying to use only embedded code to show videos and disable video upload option from tinymce media plugin. So i need to hide "General" tab on the media dialog.
I saw a similar question is asked in [tinymce](http://community.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=31633) also but unanswered. Is there someone who has done this?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to accomplish this Damitha ? Im trying to get rid of the "General" tab as well.

Comment: yeah, this question is still not answered

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Maybe this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64215669/tinymce-5-media-plugin-remove-hide-embed-tab-section-without-affecting