# TinyMCE 5 & Media plugin: Remove (hide) "Embed" tab (section) without affecting other components/controls

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I'm using TinyMCE **5** and [Media plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/media/) with the following configuration:

```js
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    menubar: false,
    plugins: [
        "media image",
    ],
    toolbar: "media image",

    media_dimensions: false,
    media_alt_source: false,
    media_poster: false,
    
    images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
    images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
       setTimeout(function () {
         success('http://moxiecode.cachefly.net/tinymce/v9/images/logo.png');
    }, 2000);
  },
});
```

Is there any way to remove (disable, hide) the "Embed" tab (section) without affecting other components/controls?

[image]

I've checked the [documentation for Media plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/media/) but there's nothing about that...

Also, applying this CSS:

```html
<style>
  .tox .tox-dialog__body-nav-item:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

hides the "Embed" tab on media-dialog, but it also hides tabs on other dialogs. For example, it would also hide the "[Upload](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/images/demo_local-upload_01.png)" tab on dialog for image.

**FIDDLE:** http://fiddle.tinymce.com/cwhaab

On Github there is a "feature-request" for this: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/6082 ... but I'm looking for a workaround (until this new feature/option becomes available).

I'm using TinyMCE 5.4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**REALLY BAD CODE ALERT!**

Unfortunately there isn't any clean way to configure editor to make it work as you want. That being said, **really bad approach** would be to filter tab by going through the tab list after media command is executed and hiding any tab which contains text **Embed**.

Take a look at [this playground demo](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/cwhaab/1):

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",
  menubar: false,
  plugins: [
    "media image",
  ],
  toolbar: "media image",
  media_dimensions: false,
  media_alt_source: false,
  media_poster: false,


  images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
  images_upload_handler: function(blobInfo, success, failure) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      success('http://moxiecode.cachefly.net/tinymce/v9/images/logo.png');
    }, 2000);
  },
  setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on('ExecCommand', (event) => {
      const command = event.command;
      if (command === 'mceMedia') {
        const tabElems = document.querySelectorAll('div[role="tablist"] .tox-tab');
        tabElems.forEach(tabElem => {
          if (tabElem.innerText === 'Embed') {
            tabElem.style.display = 'none';
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<form method="post" action="dump.php">
  <textarea name="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Dipen! Your solution is the only one working ... I'll wait few more days and then I'll accept the answer / add bounty. BTW, not sure why you say "really bad approach"... I mean, maybe it's not the most elegant solution, but I don't think it;s slowing anything down, it doesn't make it heavy on resources I think... ;)

Comment: @PeraMika Its not bad because of performance reasons as it is most efficient, it is bad because, there is no guarantee it will work across multiple library versions and user locales.

Comment: Architecture issues resolve by proper architecture because otherwise produce "ugly" workarounds. So no shame for this workaround, but shame for TinyMce.

Answer (score 1):

Just use CSS to hide the second element;

```
<style>
  .tox .tox-dialog__body-nav-item:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    menubar: false,
    plugins: [
        "media",
    ],
    toolbar: "media",
    media_dimensions: false,
    media_alt_source: false,
    media_poster: false,
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

In the real version, you should put the control inside a div and target that with the selector as well so as not to effect all tinymce controls

**Edit:**
By putting a selector I mean do the following

```
<style>
  .onlyEffectMe .tox .tox-dialog__body-nav-item:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    menubar: false,
    plugins: [
        "media",
    ],
    toolbar: "media",
    media_dimensions: false,
    media_alt_source: false,
    media_poster: false,
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <div class="onlyEffectMe">
        <textarea name="content"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your css affects other controls as well. You wrote:
`you should put the control inside a div and target that with the selector as well so as not to effect all tinymce controls` - but I don't understand this. Can you give an example?
(I updated the question to be more precise: "... without affecting other components/controls")